# In Wamp what is platform dependent

Tags: lamp, wamp

In WAMP or in LAMP which is platform dependent?? Is it php or is it apache server or mysql?? So that we have to install different packages for different platforms??

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Mishthi, the only thing that is "platform dependent" in these scenarios (LAMP vs WAMP) is really the platform/OS itself: Windows or Linux.

The "AMP" part is basically the same for both:

- "A" - Apache; your web server. This comes packaged for Windows as an installer (setup.msi or setup.exe), and as a package for Linux (.rpm/.deb/.tgz). If you want to and are adventurous enough to do so, you can also get the source code for Apache and build it yourself. That is outlined on the Apache website. In either case, pick your platform/OS, download your binary and install - good to go.
- "M" - MySQL; your database. Again, this comes packaged for Windows as an installer, or as a binary package for Linux. You can also build it from source.
- "P" - PHP (or Perl); your scripting language of choice. Same deal as the others; installer for Windows, binary package for Linux, or build it from source.

The nice thing about running LAMP instead of WAMP (aside from a better, more stable operating system, IMHO) is that you can choose to build your tools from source and customize them to what you are going to do with them. In some ways, you may be able to call that "platform dependent", but for all practical purposes, the tools (Apache, MySQL, and PHP) were written to be cross-platform as much as possible, providing a way to have the same web application run on either Windows or Linux with little, if any, change necessary to the source code of the application.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can build the tools on Windows as well, but I would not suggest it unless you like pain and suffering. :) I have found that trying to build on Windows a number of the tools that you have on Linux is much more difficult than building them on Linux. The `autoconf` and `automake` tools make the build process orders of magnitude easier on Linux; if you want to build on Windows, try and find a source bundle that has a Micrsoft build project in it so that you can build the application/library using Visual Studio - eases the pain quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a trick question, all binary code in both is platform-specific.

Comment: so does the php interpreter produces the binary code for the php scripts?? And does apache is platform dependent??

Comment: All the binary code (PE/ELF binaries/executables) is platform-dependent. The MySQL schema is platform-independent. The PHP scripts are platform-independent insofar as they don't use platform-specific functions. The httpd configuration is mostly platform-independent.

Comment: so does it mean that ...The php scripts that are written by programmer is platform-independent but the binary code produce by php interpreter is platform-dependent.

Comment: The PHP interpreter doesn't produce any binaries; rather, the PHP interpreter *is* a binary.

Comment: ok so php interpreter is platform dependent and because of this we need to install package for different binaries??

Comment: The web server is also platform-dependent. And yes, the database server too.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, all three run on both platforms, though path conventions and system calls look differently so the application code needs to be written correctly. You should be able to write PHP and a MySQL schema on Windows and port it to Linux without fuss if it's done correctly.

Comment: I think he's asking which of the products are platform-dependent, rather than developing for these products. It's not very clear, though.

Comment: Yes, specifically, you need to be careful of file/directory names and line endings - remember that on Windows, your line endings are CR-LF and on Linux they are only LF. That not only includes the strings in your code, but your application code files as well. For the most part, the extra whitespace is not an issue, but if you switch from one platform to the other and edit code on both, make sure you have a decent editor that can handle either end-of-line format. Can be a pain if you don't.

Comment: @Alex Agreed. I figured knowledge of the acronyms implied he knew the stack existed for both platforms, so he was asking about code, but even that interpretation has holes. I love answering questions where my primary task is to try to figure out what the asker is thinking.

Comment: @Alex : if that be the case, then really none of them are platform-dependent, per se. Apache, PHP/Perl, and MySQL all run on both Windows and Linux - you just need to install the binaries for whichever OS you are on.

Comment: So these binaries are used by whom?? By apache or php interpreter??

Comment: @Mishthi By "binaries" he's referring to the "programs" in LAMP or WAMP. I think there may be a language barrier affecting this question.

Comment: And does the interpreter for php produces any binary code?? An apache webserver is platform dependent??

Comment: @Stefan Mai : I believe so, too, and yes, by "binaries" I mean the "programs" themselves: apache, php, MySQL.

Comment: @Mishti Like it's been said in a few other answers, Apache, PHP, and MySQL all RUN on both platforms, but are not "platform independent" in that the code must be compiled for the platforms specifically (ie, they are not written in Java).

Comment: ok so it is like C ..C can be used for multiple platforms but the compiled programs are platform dependent...

Comment: Precisely. In fact, all 3 projects (Apache, MySQL, and PHP) are mostly C.

Comment: What does they all are written in C?? And does database files are also according to OS??

Comment: And can you pls tell me whether the php interpreter produces any binary code for the php scripts??

Comment: @Mishthi I suggest you ask questions using the provided interface. Comments are for clarifications, and it's much easier to answer questions in parts. This will also give the community a chance at interpreting and answering your questions independently. Thanks!